# Android Studio 3.5.1 with NDK 20.0 can't find cstdint

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, header-files

How do I get a cpp file in my project to find the header cstdint?

Comment: We don't know how you are building (e.g. which STL implementation are you using?).

Comment: How do I do find that?

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support

Comment: There is no Android.mk file in my project directory.

Comment: Also, how do I find android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.arguments, so I can add the argument to use c++_shared?

Comment: I added arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"  to android.defaultconfig.externalnativebuild.cmake and cstdint still isn't found

Comment: What's the error? What have you tried? What do your build scripts look like? There's no useful information in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had to add my source files to the add_library method in CMakeList.txt.

Also, I added arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" to the android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake method in the build.gradle for Module.app. I think this is the default behavior and isn't necessary though.

I made the mistake of assuming the source files were added to CMakeList.txt automatically.